# List all Stack Overflow tags in a file

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I need all of the tags used on Stack Overflow, or at least many of them, listed in a text file. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure, but as tags are available in the database, it should be possible to run a SEDE query, and export the results.

Comment: I have no knoledge/experience in that whatsovere, can you help ?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with SEDE too, sorry. But enough people around here are.

Comment: ok, no problem, thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

OK, it was easy enough:

```sql
select tagname from tags;
```

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/373981/all-tags)